# Magento2 : Why I'm redirect to Empty Cart After Checkout?

Tags: checkout, redirect, shopping-cart, magento2.2.6

I am running Magento 2.2.6. I noticed my analytics data seemed off so I went in and checked and I am only receiving about 50% of my transactions. I can see the transaction id so I have compared the data and nothing stands out. It happens to both logged in and logged out customers, 95% of our sales are credit cards so it is almost always credit cards. On my dev site when I test everything goes through fine but it redirects to an empty shopping cart instead of the success page. There is also nothing in the logs.

How can I make it redirect to the success page?

Comment: Is order is placed?

Comment: @Rizwan Order is placed and went through just fine

Comment: please try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/55898/51548 or
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34469750/5577053

Comment: Is there any custom code written to redirect to your empty cart page.?

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma No custom code. It is a vanilla checkout.

Comment: @Rizwan Already found that thread and tried everything in there.